# Set attributes on class from a dict

Tags: python-3.x, python-descriptors

I successfully implemented a Descriptor to clean up my code and it worked fine so far. At this moment my code looks basically like this

```py
class ABC:
  att1 = Descriptor(arg1)
  att2 = Descriptor(arg2)
  att3 = Descriptor(arg3)
```

However, to further reduce repititions, Id like to do something like this

```py
class ABC:
  att_arg = {'att1':arg1,
             'att2':arg2,
             'att3':arg3}

  for att, arg in att_arg.items():
     setattr(ABC, att, Descriptor(arg))
```

but this leads to a `NameError: name 'ABC' is not defined`.
Already thought about a wrapper class to do this, but does anyone know an elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

What about do it in the constructor? From there you can use `self` object to set the attributes:

```
class ABC:
    ATTR_ARG = {'att1':arg1,
                'att2':arg2,
                'att3':arg3}

    def __init__(self):
        for attr, arg in ATTR_ARG.items():
            setattr(self, attr, Descriptor(arg))
```

Comment: Does not work with the Descriptor. Only works if the attributes are set at class level. If set in the constructor, the attribute does not return its value but the Descriptor object itself.